# Trying to install macOS Mojave on a mid-2012 MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, mojave, software-update, software

I've been trying to install macOS Mojave on this thing for a few hours now but I've come across a few problems. If I try to update it through the appstore software updates it gives me error (102), you obviously can't find older versions of macOS on the appstore anymore so that didn't work either. A few people recommended me to open the page through safari but I can't open the installer from safari into the store. I don't know how exactly to explain what I mean so I'll attach an image. No download button, can't open it in the store.

(If you haven't realized I'm currently running on 10.8.5), help would be much appreciated! I need this thing for school since my other laptop quite literally gave up.

Comment: Jump via El Capitan &/or High Sierra first - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos/309400#309400 Note that MBP will run Catalina, which it usually the oldest OS new apps will run on.

Comment: It still won't let me open it in the app store, I've opened the link in safari but only like half of it loads and there's no way to like press download or install or open it in the store or anything along those lines.

Comment: It's because you're on Mountain Lion.  Use a tool like [installinstallmacosx.py](https://github.com/munki/macadmin-scripts/blob/main/installinstallmacos.py) to download the Catalina installer.

Comment: This is gonna sound stupid but I've opened the link and I don't really understand how to use it- I don't really see any files to install. I see code but I don't know what to do with this. Am I supposed to paste it into the terminal or something? ;-;

Comment: Download https://raw.githubusercontent.com/munki/macadmin-scripts/main/installinstallmacos.py, make it executable and run it.

Comment: Instructions on how to use it are here: https://github.com/munki/macadmin-scripts

Answer (score 2):

Apple has changed how OS X and macOS interface with the Apps Store may times since the release of OS X Mount Lion. Apple provides updates which allow access to the Apps Store going back as far as OS X El Capitan. So you probably should first try to upgrade to the latest version of OS X El Capitan.

You should not need the App Store to download and upgrade to El Capitan. Follow the instructions on the Apple website [How to get old versions of macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683). The URL is https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683.  Once upgraded to El Capitan, you will probably need to install any additional available El Capitan updates. Afterwards, you can try using the Apps Store.